# Cisco 3925 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module not found message at boot up

Tags: cisco

A while back one of our 3925s bit the dust.  I figured I would take it home and see if I can revive it, maybe use it in my lab.  So I connect my console cable, and power up the router.  Everything seems to be fine then I get this message:

System Bootstrap, Version 15.1(1r)T1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2010 by cisco Systems, Inc.

Total memory size = 1024 MB - DIMM0 = 512 MB, DIMM1 = 512 MB

Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module not found

I don't remember it having a VPN module in the first place, so I thought this was a little odd.  I pulled out the main board, and I didn't see anything resembling a VPN module.  It seemed to hang on this, though maybe it's search was delaying the boot process.  Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The VPN module looks like this:

[image]

and fits into the ISM slot, which is part number 7 below.

[image]

On some Cisco models there's also an "ISM" LED on the chassis such that you can see without opening it up if the chassis recognizes any module installed.

So I guess the first step is, does the chassis contain a module?  If yes, and you remove it, does it boot fine?

Comment: Tedwin, thanks for your help.  My board is slightly different then what you have pictured.  Which leads me to believe that it is embedded.  I booted the router up and left it there.  I came back about a half hour later and it just showed the same message.  It must be stuck on something, guess its a boat anchor now.

Answer (score 0):

Data Sheet says: Embedded IP Security with Secure Sockets Layer (IPSec/SSL) VPN hardware acceleration
●  Embedded hardware encryption acceleration is enhanced to provide higher scalability, which, combined with an optional Cisco IOS Software Security license, enables WAN link security and VPN services (both IPSec and SSL acceleration).
●  The onboard encryption hardware outperforms the advanced integration modules (AIMs) of previous generations.